# Rails associations for a fairly simple notification system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, mongoid, associations, modeling

I'm trying to set up a notification system in Rails, along with mongoid (but I don't think this is mongoid specific).

The basic structure is like this - Every notification has a notifier (the one who is responsible for the notification) and a notifee (the one who receives the notification). When a user A comments on user B's post (in a blog system for example), the User A becomes the notifier and the User B is the notifiee.

**User.rb**

```
# nothing in here
```

**Notification.rb**

```
has_one :notifier, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :notifiee, :class_name => "User"
```

However, when I do:

```
@notification = Notification.new
@notification.notifier = current_user
@notification.notifiee = User.first #Just for the sake of the example
@notification.save
```

I get this error:

> **Problem**: When adding a(n) User to Notification#notifier, Mongoid could
>   not determine the inverse foreign key to set. The attempted key was
>   'notifiee_id'.Summary: When adding a document to a relation, Mongoid
>   attempts to link the newly added document to the base of the relation
>   in memory, as well as set the foreign key to link them on the database
>   side. In this case Mongoid could not determine what the inverse
>   foreign key was.Resolution: If an inverse is not required, like a
>   belongs_to or has_and_belongs_to_many, ensure that :inverse_of => nil
>   is set on the relation. If the inverse is needed, most likely the
>   inverse cannot be figured out from the names of the relations and you
>   will need to explicitly tell Mongoid on the relation what the inverse
>   is.

What could I be doing wrong? Or, is there a better way to model this??

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: post schema for notifications. And also the error is pretty clear. You dont need inverse relations so set it to nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably go for the following associations:

User:

```
has_many :notifications_as_notifier, :class_name=>'Notification', :foreign_key=>'notifier_id'
has_many :notifications_as_notifiee, :class_name=>'Notification', :foreign_key=>'notifiee_id'
```

Notification:

```
belongs_to :notifier, :class_name=>'User', :foreign_key=>'notifier_id'
belongs_to :notifiee, :class_name=>'User', :foreign_key=>'notifiee_id'
```

Your `notifications` table should have `notifier_id` and `notifiee_id`.

Now you can do,

```
@notification = Notification.new
@notification.notifier = current_user
@notification.notifiee = User.first #Just for the sake of the example
@notification.save
```

---

**What I find questionable in your setup:**

You have,

```
has_one :notifier, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :notifiee, :class_name => "User"
```

When you use `has_on`, then the other relation (table) must have a foreign key referencing the parent. Here `users` must have a column `notification_id` or something. This is impractical because a single user has many notifications (based on your explanations).

Secondly, you are associating Notification to User through two relationships but you are mentioning anything about the foreign key to use to enforce the association.

And why do you not have an inverse relation in the User model? Would it not help if you had access to something like: `current_user.notifications_as_notifier` ??

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I think it would be great to have current_user.notifications_as_notifier..indeed.